# Monitoring EC2 instances and alerting with PagerDuty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, alert, newrelic

I already know how to integrate NewRelic and PagerDuty for a server. Recently I have added an EC2 instance and I am able to see the plots and all the information in the NewRelic. I am not able to integrate that EC2 with PagerDuty for alerting. Can you please let me know if NewRelic supports it for EC2?

Answer (score 0):

New Relic's alerting integrations should work the same for any monitored app, regardless of the platform.  If you're having trouble integrating a particular app with PagerDuty, please file a support request with support@newrelic.com

Answer (score 0):

You can find the information on how to do it here:

http://www.pagerduty.com/docs/guides/new-relic-integration-guide/